# Elastic: startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have implemented a search using elastic. The below is my `Analyse` configuration

```
 $aAnalizerArray = [
        "edgeTokenizer" => [
            "tokenizer"=>"edgeTokenizer",
            "filter" => [
                "word_delimiter_graph",
                "lowercase",
                "unique"
            ]
        ],
    ];

  $wbTokenizer = [
        "edgeTokenizer"=>[
            "type"=> "nGram", //edgeNGram
            "min_gram"=>"2",
            "max_gram"=> "8",
            "token_chars"=> [
                "letter",
                "digit"
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

However, when I insert `SeaShell Inc` it gives me error like below:

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards startOffset=1,endOffset=3,lastStartOffset=3 for field 'company_name'"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards startOffset=1,endOffset=3,lastStartOffset=3 for field 'company_name'"},"status":400}`

But if it is `Sea Shell Inc`, then there is no problem. My elastic version is 6.X

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Hello,did you find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This issue can happen because of configuration parameters of word_delimiter_graph, as some
Setting in word_delimiter_graph can produces multi-position tokens, which are not supported by indexing. The configuration parameters that can cause this issue are listed below:

adjust_offsets: when set to "false"

catenate_all: when set to "true"

catenate_numbers: when set to "true"

catenate_words: when set to "true"

preserve_original: when set to "true"

for more information you can check documentation of Elastic search [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-graph-tokenfilter.html).